# Writing to /dev/log/main from command line

Tags: adb, logging

It is possible to write encoded messages into `/dev/log/main` and then see them in the `adb logcat` output.

The command should be executable through adb from the host PC. Ideally, it should look like:

```
adb shell ... my log message
```

Is there some way to encode the logs without installing anything?

So far, we have used very simple native application, which will print whatever is passed over its command line to the log.

Comment: Are you asking from a user's view (some context would help then), or are you looking for "code pieces" to establish that in your app?

Comment: @Izzy edited the question. Hope it is better now

Answer (score 4):

Write the following in terminal (replace 123456789 with the device serial number/id):

```
adb -s 123456789 shell log -t "TAG" "MESSAGE"
```